# How to migrate SQLite database to an encrypted SQLite database? (Titanium)

Tags: database, sqlite, encryption, appcelerator, migrate

I have an existing app built with appcelerator's titanium. It currently has a database existing on it, but I want to upgrade it to an encrypted database. I am using appcelerator's encrypted database module. If I delete the local database and build the app clean it is fine, the problem is when I try to migrate from the existing database to the encrypted one. I get this error:

```
file is encrypted or is not a database
message = "Couldn't open database and migrate";
Script Error Module "alloy/models/table.js" failed to leave a valid exports object
```

My exports definition looks like this:

```
'config': {
    columns: columns,
    defaults: {},
    adapter: {
        "type": "enc.db",
        "collection_name": "table",
        "idAttribute": "LocalID",
        "db_name": "_alloy_.enc.db"
    }
},
```

Comment: did you solve this?